# Where to look for differences when the CSS is seemingly the same?

Tags: css, difference

the answers I found on the Internet are all pretty specific. So what should I generally do when two elements, their children, and their parents have seemingly the same CSS attributes, but look different?

Comment: Compare computed styles in browser console

Comment: Please provide some example..thanx

Answer (score 3):

Inspect the element and look at the styles tab of your developer tools. The style rules appear in the order they are applied and the top most rule is with the highest priority.

[image]

Comment: I know about this and this is the place where they apear to be the same.